# Что в скрипте NodeJS может нагружать CPU и как отследить где именно в коде возникает такая ситуация?

Tags: node.js, оптимизация

Стал замечать, что один скрипт сокет-сервера нагружает очень сильно процессор. Причем если отключить этот скрипт, то нагрузка на процессор пропадёт. Подскажите, пожалуйста, на что в первую очередь стоит обратить внимание.

Comment: это же логично - на содержимое скрипта. Без этого сложно что то советовать.

Comment: @KoVadim 900 строк

Comment: Тогда придется методом деления попалам. Удалеете половину кода и смотрите - проблема ушла - значит она была в удаленном куске. И так до победного конца

Comment: Мы даже не знаем что ваш скрипт делает. Может он считает миллион знаков числа пи…

Answer (score 1):

Могу посоветовать использовать стандартный линуксовый `perf`. Запускаете ноду с флагом `--perf-basic-prof`. Сгенерируется `.map` файл. Потом в этом же каталоге открываете `perf report --no-children` и у вас в консоли отобразится красивая интерактивная табличка.

[Подробнее](https://mrale.ph/blog/2018/02/03/maybe-you-dont-need-rust-to-speed-up-your-js.html#profiling-the-pure-javascript-version) в блоге вячеслава егорова